# Wrap floating DIVS Responsive view

Tags: css, mobile, web, responsive-design

i am just wondering  if i have layout like this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left"> Left </div>
<div class="right"> Right </div>
</div>
```

changing view port to 320  needs right div appear first and left div below it , Is this possible ??????

Answer (score 0):

yes. just use the flex-box setup on the pertinent media query, as exemplified below and the boxes will show up reversed.

```
<html><head></head><body><div class="container" style="
    display: -webkit-flex;
">
  <div class="left" style="
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    background: lightgray;
"> Left </div>
  <div class="right" style="
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    background: yellow;
    -webkit-order: -1;
"> Right </div>
</div> 
</body></html>
```

Original source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: ok, please check the source of this page: http://www.petercarrero.com/reverse.html (code geared towards webkit, but the same cross-browser solution is available on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Answer (score -1):

It is possible and widely used. Take a look at this mobile first approach:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right"> Right </div>
<div class="left"> Left </div>
</div>
```

This will be rendered one box below another on mobile. And now we use CSS to rearrange them on bigger screens (above 320px):

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 481px) {
  .left { float: left; }
  .right { float: right; }
}
```

Comment: OP wants without changing html order.

Comment: This is the right approach when designing for mobile. Javascript DOM manipulation is another approach but has poor performance issues on mobile and should NOT be used.